# Troubleshooting homepage div positioning

Tags: html, css

Would anyone be able to help explain why our homepage title on firefox appears far to the right of the page compared to chrome?

[www.volleyballusa.com](https://www.volleyballusa.com)

```
<div id="videoDiv-home">
<div id="videoBlock-home"><video id="video" width="320" height="240" 
preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"><source 
src="https://www.volleyballusa.com/content/introOpt-transcode.mp4" 
type="video/mp4" /><object id="video" width="320" height="240" data="https://www.volleyballusa.com/javascript/tinymce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="https://www.volleyballusa.com/javascript/tinymce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="url=/content/introOpt-transcode.mp4&amp;poster=/" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true" /></object> 
</video>

<div id="videoMessage-home">
    <h1 class="vidtitle">Buy American Made.</h1>
    <a class="big learnmore w-button" href="https://www.volleyballusa.com/court-
construction/">Proudly Manufacturing Volleyball Nets, Poles, Pads, Boundary 
Lines, Etc.</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see anything different in firefox and chrome when I test

Comment: Different browsers render HTML/CSS differently. There's no way 100% around this. Can you post your CSS and maybe we can give you some more advice.

Comment: Could you be more specific with the homepage 'title'? I see no difference in the design in my FF (56.0.2) and Chrome (62.0.3)

Comment: It may have to do with the browser width.  In Chrome I notice that the two icons on the right disappear while shrinking the window.  Then they reappear when the @media kicks in to swap the CSS.

Comment: appreciate the quick responses. Here is the CSS

`#videoDiv-home { width: 100%; height: 500px; }`

`#videoBlock-home { height: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; overflow: hidden; }`

`#videoBlock-home video { object-fit: cover; object-position: 50% 50%; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

`#videoMessage-home { position: absolute; text-align: center; }`

Comment: are there firefox related css I can write to match it for chrome?

Comment: None of this screams of browser specific CSS. Also, I just tested the website in both browsers and like others I can report that I saw no significant differences. Are you using updated browser versions? Could you maybe attach a screenshot to show us what you mean?

Comment: Also when expanding on your question from comments feedback (as with the CSS), it's usually better to edit the question itself. This way it doesn't get stuck in the comments.

Comment: Wait a second, I see that you're using flex. This is only supported in very new browsers. I would bet that the version of Firefox you're using is out of date.

Comment: sure thing. here's a link to my screen
[link]https://imgur.com/a/mg6bm

Comment: I see...I am newer to the company and the only one with some dev background (beginner). I think a web design firm or previous employee used flex on the majority of the website. How/where do you see that from what I shared? Also, what do you recommend doing moving forward? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using Flexbox for your screen layout. It's a wonderful addition to CSS3, but it only has support in new browsers. See [list of supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for Flexbox. This is likely the source of your formatting issues, not the browsers themselves.

To support moderately older browsers, you need to use vendor prefixes. The following are the appropriate [vendor prefixes for Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/flexbox-prefixes/).

```
display: -webkit-box; // for older versions of chrome/safari
display: -moz-box; // for older versions of firefox
display: -ms-flexbox; // for older versions of Internet Explorer
display: -webkit-flex; // for older versions of chrome/safari
display: flex; // for modern browsers
```

That being said, older browsers will not support flexbox even with vendor prefixes. One way to handle this would be to use fallback CSS. This means designing your CSS so that a newer browser will use the flexbox specs, but an older browser will use alternative specs. I haven't tried this out personally, but some people seem to have luck using `display:table` as [a good alternative](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=table).

If it's really important to you that your website render well on older system, I suggest you stick to more established CSS. For grid-like layouts, I would recommend [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), specifically it's grid system. It's pretty easy to learn, and it has excellent support on older browsers and even on mobile. That being said, most of your users will probably have browsers new enough to display Flexbox, especially with vendor prefixes, so it's probably not necessary to rewrite your entire codebase.

Comment: So a large portion of our website was designed by a previous company and looks like they used flexbox. Now I can imagine numerous customers potentiallly arriving to our site and seeing things out of wack.

I think my plan will be to rebuild the theme in bootstrap. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @EdgarGrepo I think I may have led you down the wrong path a bit. Flexbox is actually a bit better supported than I initially thought. Please see my updated answer, particularly the section on vendor prefixes. This should solve your display problems for most of your customers without having to rewrite your code.

Comment: To be clear, Bootstrap is still a great framework and I'd still highly recommend it (even with flexbox). But I don't think using it is necessary to solve your problem.